# Android. Catching moment when OS releases application from memory

Tags: android, release

Is there any method or smth like that, where I can catch releasing my app from memory?

I need to save some data before it happend. So if it impossible in Android, give me some advices to solve this problem by another way.

Comment: Save your state in onSaveInstanceState  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: Follow the life cycle methods and you dont need to think of the rest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any method or smth like that, where I can catch releasing my app from memory?

No.

> give me some advices to solve this problem by another way

Save the data when the data changes. Data in memory is **only a cache**; if you need the data to live past the end of your process, you need to save that data when it changes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow your advice. Cause I have a bad practice with using onSaveInstanceState or onDestroy (these methods call in many different situations like device blocking or going to another fragment).

Comment: And it needs a lot of flags and checking statement of many another fragments to control data saving by using these methods.